# Error: 1452 - Insert operation failed after adding trigger

Tags: mysql

I have the following schema:

user table:

```
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra             |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
| user_id       | int          | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment    |
| account_type  | varchar(10)  | NO   |     | NULL              |                   |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
```

student table:

```
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| student_id     | int          | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id        | int          | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| specialization | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The `user_id` in student table is a foreign key from `user` table. 
Adding data to both tables in order was working well, until I introduced this trigger

```
create trigger after_user_insert
-> after insert on user for each row
-> begin
-> if new.account_type like 'student' then
-> insert into student(user_id) values (LAST_INSERT_ID());
-> end if;
-> end;//
```

Now, it gives

> error 1452: (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`studentmanager`.`student`, CONSTRAINT `student_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`user_id`))

Comment: Your error refers to `student` table but your trigger refers to `doctor`...

Comment: I changed it and yet the error remains same.

Comment: @DebarghaRoy Please [edit] your question to include the query you are executing to insert the row(s) in the `user` table. The function call `LAST_INSERT_ID()` might not be useful here, specially when you add two rows. Also, add the `CREATE TABLE` statements of your tables as well, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query for SQL related questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This really took me a while to get my head around hehe.

```
CREATE TRIGGER after_user_insert
AFTER insert ON user
FOR EACH ROW
insert into student(user_id) SELECT (user_id) FROM user 
WHERE new.account_type LIKE 'student' ORDER BY user_id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

RESULT:

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
**Query #1**

    SELECT * FROM user;

| user_id | account_type |
| ------- | ------------ |
| 1       | student      |
| 2       | student      |
| 3       | not          |
| 4       | student      |
| 5       | student      |
| 6       | not          |
| 7       | not          |
| 8       | student      |

---
**Query #2**

    SELECT * FROM student;

| student_id | user_id |
| ---------- | ------- |
| 1          | 1       |
| 2          | 2       |
| 3          | 4       |
| 4          | 5       |
| 5          | 8       |

---
```

[View this working example on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ifZukyTWnG3e4XeMcAqzUU/0)

I'm no expert and I do this for fun so someone please correct me if I'm wrong. I believe you can not have LIKE without SELECT. As well as LAST_INSERT_ID(). And i forgot in process of this what was wrong with keys, but there was obliviously couple of things wrong here. I THINK.

I wouldn't mind second opinion about my query also. But as much as I tested it is correct.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I wanted to try the using the Select statement but was a bit confused about the approach and it's implication on batch operations.

Comment: @DebarghaRoy You might want to use the `new.user_id` column to get the id of the newly inserted row.

Comment: @Progman ORDER BY + DESC + LIMIT insure you get one last new user_id but it would work also  adding new. in this how it already is.  Just  DebarghaRoy be careful to add it on right user :)

Comment: @DebarghaRoy Yeah it gets confusing. I like to solve it and look at it as puzzle, I spent hours on yours hehe. There are also lot of limitation that you find out about hard way and overlapping logic's that don't work together.  But there's solution for everything. Mostly heh.